How to Deserialize Binary byte[] Data from IDistributedCache in ASP.NET Core?
Here's a question based on your scenario that you can ask on StackOverflow:

Title:
How can I correctly deserialize byte[] data from IDistributedCache that results in a binary format?

Body:
I am retrieving a byte[] from IDistributedCache in my ASP.NET Core application, which was serialized using the session management system (ISession.CommitAsync). When I try to deserialize the byte[], I receive the following error:
{'0x02' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.}

I tried converting the byte[] back to a string using:
var jsonString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);

But this gives me strange and unreadable strings, suggesting that the data is in a binary format.
Here's what I know:

The data was serialized by ISession.CommitAsync.
I'm trying to deserialize it into a Dictionary<string, object>.
I don't know the exact serialization format.

I've tried using both UTF8.GetString and BinaryFormatter for deserialization, but neither works as expected.
Some questions I have:

How can I correctly deserialize the byte[] stored in IDistributedCache?
Could the data be compressed or serialized in a specific format by ASP.NET Core sessions, and how should I handle it?


If you use chat gpt, at least try to clean the post out of the chat gpt comment :)

Thanks, wanted fix some my spelling grammar

There is no single answer to this; IDistributedCache is a storage abstraction only - it doesn't convey any meaning to the data, and what is stored is entirely opaque to that layer. To interpret the data, you need to know exactly what stored it and how, or better: ask that layer to read and interpret the data for you. It is a bit like asking "I have a file on disk; how do I correctly interpret the file contents?".
Likewise, ISession.CommitAsync is an abstraction; you'd need to know which concrete implementation of ISession stored that data.
